# Why are SingleTop activities sometimes created multiple times

Tags: android

I have an activity with a launch mode set to `singleTop` in the manifest. However if this activity is started multiple times through `startActivity` called one after another, multiple instances are still created.

Here is the code that demonstrates the behavior. MainActivity displays a single button that start `SingleTopActivity` twice when clicked. `SingleTopActivity` displays a message received from `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startActivity);
        startActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startSingleTopActivity("first");
                startSingleTopActivity("second");
            }
        });
    }

    private void startSingleTopActivity(@NonNull String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SingleTopActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SingleTopActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class SingleTopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";

    private TextView mMessage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_top);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("SingleTopActivity");

        mMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        mMessage.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        String message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        mMessage.setText(mMessage.getText() + " " + message);
    }
}
```

When no additional intent flags are present `SingleTopActivity` with `second` message is launched. When navigated back `SingleTopActivity` with `first` message appears instead of `MainActivity`.

However if launched in debugger (so starting activity takes longer time due to breakpoints etc.), or when flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` or `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` are set only one instance of `SingleTopActivity` is launched, as expected.

Why does `singleTop` not work as expected in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) says, if a activity is set to `singletop`, only if the activity is in top of the task, it won't be created again.
In your code,when you call `startSingleTopActivity("second");`,the top activity of the task is `MainActivity` not `SingleTopActivity`, so it will be created twice.